# Laptop screen dimming

Tags: display, battery, battery-life

On my laptop, when I press the Fn keys that dim the screen - is Windows doing the dimming, or the hardware?

Are if it is the hardware, would using software to dim it further improve battery life?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is Windows doing the dimming, or the hardware?

Well, both. Windows is instructing the hardware through a motherboard driver to dim the screen 's backlight. It's the same as when you tell your computer to eject the CD drive, for example. It sends a message to hardware to do something, and it does it.

> If it is the hardware, would using software to dim it further improve battery life?

Windows is simply telling a light at the bottom of your screen to turn down. Using any software (built-in to Windows or 3rd party) will of course improve battery life. Less light = less power draw = more battery life.

Using third party software (like [Dimmer](http://www.nelsonpires.com/software/dimmer/), for instance), you could turn down the backlight beyond what Windows allows you to, conserving even more power.